# Understanding output of lda() in R

Tags: machine-learning, classification

I have a classification problem of classifying mobile price. The data set contains information about mobile phone's credentials. There are 4 independent variables, namely ram, battery-power,px_height, px_width and dependent variable price_range has 4 classes: High, Low, Medium, Very High.

For this I use    `lda()` in `R` as (`df.trn2` is object in which dataset stored.)

```
lda(price_range~.,df.trn2)
```

and I got following output:

`Call:`

`lda(price_range ~ ., data = df.trn2)`

`Prior probabilities of groups:`

`High       Low    Medium Very High`

`0.2500000 0.2500000 0.2477778 0.2522222`

`Group means:`

`battery_power px_height px_width       ram`

`High           1235.378  629.0089 1220.502 2589.2178`

`Low            1112.684  534.6044 1151.729  781.3156`

`Medium         1234.612  668.2668 1254.439 1676.8946`

`Very High      1382.057  746.2577 1375.555 3447.1300`

`Coefficients of linear discriminants:`

`LD1           LD2           LD3`

`battery_power -0.0016592803  0.0012684042  1.753402e-04`

`px_height     -0.0009583499  0.0007982419 -2.460915e-03`

`px_width      -0.0008649503  0.0012577421  2.122012e-03`

`ram           -0.0030645115 -0.0002619690 -2.928941e-06`

`Proportion of trace:`

`LD1    LD2    LD3`

`0.9986 0.0012 0.0001`

Now, I unable to understand what is **`Coefficients of linear discriminants:`**  in the output and what is its interpretation. Please explain it or give some reference of it.  Thank you